# How to treat a single row of matrix in R as a matrix object

Tags: r

I have an R script that removes random rows from an nxm (n row, m column) matrix depending on which elements occur in a data set. I have a conditional statement that terminates if there are no rows remaining. This works fine if there are 0 rows, but not if there is one.

For example, if I have

```
m1 = rbind(c(1,2),c(1,4),c(2,3),c(2,4))
```

and I delete all rows

```
m1 = m1[-c(1,2,3,4),]
```

the conditional statement

```
if(length(m1[,1]) > 0)
```

evaluates correctly to FALSE and the program terminates, since the object m1 is a 0x2 matrix. However, if I delete all but one row, e.g.

```
m1 = m1[-c(1,2,4),]
```

the same conditional statement does not evaluate because the remaining row is no longer treated as a matrix object of dimension 1xn, but rather as a numeric vector, so dim, length(m[,1]) etc are undefined.

Is there some way to preserve a single row as a 1xn matrix object, other than checking if only a single row remains and applying t(as.matrix(m1)), which would be a very clumsy approach?

I've appended my complete script below, but the details of the script shouldn't be necessary to address this question. The while(temp_mat[,1] > 0) is the step that breaks if I have a single row (but works fine if there are none or any number of rows > 1)

```
seq_to_mask = function(mat){
temp_mat = mat
to_mask = c()
iter = 0
while(length(temp_mat[,1])>0){
    all_instances = c(temp_mat[,1],temp_mat[,2])
    #number of times a sample appears
    occurrences = sort(table(all_instances))
    max_instances = as.numeric(names(occurrences)[length(occurrences)])
    posits = which(temp_mat[,1]==max_instances | temp_mat[,2]==max_instances)
    to_mask = c(to_mask, max_instances)
    temp_mat = temp_mat[-posits,]
    iter = iter + 1
}
return(to_mask)
}
```

Comment: With your changes made, `m1[,1] > 0#
logical(0)` and not FALSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason seems to be the coercion of `matrix` to `vector` when there is a single row/column.  We can use `drop = FALSE` (by default it is `drop = TRUE`)

```
m1 <- m1[-c(1, 2, 4), , drop = FALSE]
```